# ¿Como crear un índice que se pueda cambiar fácilmente?

Tags: html, web

De primeras me funcionó tu solución, alexis33 pero ahora al aplicarla a mi proyecto no funciona, el php está activado pero no me muestra el include_once, como si no existiera. En la página principal tengo esto

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="keywords" content="programming, html, css, JavaScript, tetonala1312, web page">
  <meta name="description" content="A web page that teaches from novice to expert the programming languages: html, css and JavaScript">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="author" content="tetonala1312">
  <title>tetonala1312</title>
</head>
<?php
include_once '/resources/prueba.php';
?>
<body>
 <div id="html">
   <h3>Aprende html</h3>
   <a href="https://tetonala1312.github.io/cybernala/Resources/Html.html"><h4>Empezar curso de html</h4></a>
 </div>
 <div id="css">
   <h3>Aprende css</h3>
   <a href="https://tetonala1312.github.io/cybernala/Resources/Css.html"><h4>Empezar curso de css</h4></a>
 </div>
</body>
<footer>
<br>
<h4>Realizado por tetonala1312</h4>
<br>
<a href="https://tetonala1312.github.io/cybernala/index.html">Inicio</a>
<br>
<a href="https://tetonala1312.github.io/cybernala/Resources/Html.html">Html</a>
<br>
<a href="https://tetonala1312.github.io/cybernala/Resources/Css.html">CSS</a>
<br>
<a href="#">JavaScript</a>
<br>
<br>
</footer>
</html>
```

En resources/prueba.php tengo

```
<header>
 <div id="titulobarrasuperior">
   <br>
   <h2>Cybernala</h2>
 </div>
 <div id="subtitulo">
   <h6>Una p&aacutegina que enseña desarrollo web desde cero para todos los niveles</h4>
 </div>
 <div id="menu">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="https://tetonala1312.github.io/cybernala/index.html" id="aqui">Inicio</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://tetonala1312.github.io/cybernala/Resources/Html.html">Html</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://tetonala1312.github.io/cybernala/Resources/Css.html">CSS</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</header>
```

Y al ponerlo en el servidor no me carga la parte de /resources/prueba.php Solo me sale lo primero
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Quiero repetir ese código en muchas páginas y que al modificar el código en una se cambie en todas sin tener que ir una por una

Comment: Si trabajas con algún lenguaje del lado del servidor, puedes tener el índice en un archivo aparte y tan solo tendrías que incluirlo en cada archivo en una sola línea. Por ejemplo, en PHP se utiliza, entre otras funciones, una llamada `include_once` que hace justo lo que menciono. Así, cuando quieras hacer cambios en el índice y afectar la vista en los demás archivos que lo incluyen, solo tendrás que trabajar sobre el archivo que contiene al índice.

Comment: ¿Me podrías explicar como hacerlo exactamente?                                                              Tengo php en el servidor

Comment: Puedes crear un archivo "indice.php", y en los demás archivos en donde necesites el índice solo tendrías que colocar lo siguiente: `<?php include once 'indice.php'; ?>`, considerando para ello la ruta en la que se encuentra el archivo indice.php.

Answer (score 0):

Ya que trabajas con PHP, puedes crear un archivo `indice.php` en el cual tendrás exclusivamente el código del índice. Luego, en los demás archivos que tienen que mostrar el índice, solo tendrás que incluirlo de esta manera:

```
<?php
include_once 'indice.php';
?>
```

Lo anterior tendrás que colocarlo en el lugar en el que deseas mostrar el índice, además de considerar la ruta del archivo. Por ejemplo, si el archivo `indice.php` lo tengo en la ruta `miProyecto/includes/indice.php` y lo quiero mostrar en otro archivo que se encuentra en `miProyecto/directoriox/ejemplo.php`, tendrás que escribir algo así:

```
<?php
include_once '../includes/indice.php';
?>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, lamento la tardanza pero tenía que comprobarlo por si acaso. Espero que te vaya bien y sigas ayudando a otra gente